# How do I get the column names in multiple datasets in python?

Tags: python

I am studying Python now.
I'm handling 12 datasets for case study and I want to check the columns names of each datasets.

- names of datasets : data_202101, data_202102, ... , data_202112

I wrote 12 same codes to check each datasets' column names like bottom.

```
data_202101.columns
data_202102.columns
...
data_202112.columns
```

but I want to use only 1 code.
How I can do that?

I tried bottom code but it doesn't work.

```
for i in range(1:10):
   data = 'data_2021'+i
   data.columns
```

I am really a beginner so please help me. :)

Comment: The last code creates a string, how do you access the dataset columns property? Is there an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code maybe can help

```
print(["data_20210"+str(i)+".columns" for i in range(1,11)])
```